# US8618969: Missing a key reference

Tags: patentability, non-obviousness, us8618969

S. Balasubramanian et al., "Systematic analysis of interleaved digital-to-analog converters", Circuits and Systems II: Express Briefs, IEEE, 2011.

Much of the claims overlap with the content of this article!

Comment: I imagine you did see another one of your papers listed on the patent. Relative to the claims would the one not cited be more relevant than the one that was cited? In patents, the applicant only has a responsibility to list what they know of and no specific responsibility to do any searching. Also, you can follow all of the written back-and-forth between the applicant and the examiner via a USPTO site called USPTO Pubic PAIR. You should be able to see how relevant your cited work was to the examination.

Comment: Yes I did notice my earlier paper to be cited. However, the one not cited is more relevant; it was a theoretic evaluation of this interleaved architecture and also details the variants that are claimed in this patent.